# Why do GDT and IDT haven't a better define?

Tags: architecture, x86, operating-system, intel, osdev

I'm learning Intel x86 architecture, I wonder why don't GDT have a well structed like this:

`base(32bit) | limit(16bit) | acces(8bit) | gran(8bit)`

but

`limit(16bit) | base(16bit) | base_mid(8bit) | access(8bit) | gran(8bit) | base_high(8bit)`

Does Intel like to be "eccentric" or it has some reasons here?

Comment: Ask the Intel hardware designers.

Comment: Why somebody down vote my question? I just don't understand why Intel's designer like to fragment the value of some registers but not leave it sequentially, I think if these are no reasons, they wouldn't do it

Comment: It's probably because of hardware design constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, although I initially voted to close this question as off-topic, you're being persistent enough in your seek of knowledge. The answer to your question is rather simple: Protected mode was introduced in 80286, which is a 16-bit CPU.
Segment Descriptor back then had pretty alligned structure:
[image]

Bytes #6 and #7 of the Segment Descriptor got extended in 80386 to handle 32-bit addressing and yet remain compatible with 80286.